# How to make Sqlmap obtain administrator rights for database?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap, dvwa

I'm using sqlmap to exploit databases in a DVWA-project.

However, after having exploited the database, I executed the following command to learn that the user is dvwa@%:

```
sqlmap -u "http://192.168.71.130/dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli/?id=2&Submit=Submit#" -p id --cookie="security=low; PHPSESSID=kikm4b9s9tdk5kq21cs20jt9j1;" --current-user
```

I'm trying to `INSERT` something into the tables, with these commands:

```
sqlmap -u "http://192.168.71.130/dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli/?id=2&Submit=Submit#" -p id --cookie="security=low; PHPSESSID=kikm4b9s9tdk5kq21cs20jt9j1;" --sql-query="INSERT INTO guestbook (comment,name) VALUES ('foo','bar');"
```

However, this fails - although a basic `SELECT` statement works fine.

I guess the dvwa@% user doesn't have privileges to `INSERT/UPDATE`.

Is it possible for sqlmap to automatically obtain administrator privileges for the database (in this case DVWA)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you are inserting into a SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE query you can only issue INSERT statements if stacked queries are available (you have to close the original query and start a new SQL statement). This is a limitation of the SQL language.

2) Privilege escalation would require a vulnerability in the database server or one of the stored procedures. Check the server version and look for stored procedures that execute as privileged user (e.g. [EXECUTE AS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql) statement in case of SQL Server). After you find a vulnerability you should execute the trigger instructions, which can be problematic if you don't have stacked queries.

Comment: So, 2) requires manual effort? This is not something that is automated, right?

Comment: It depends, some of the techniques are automated as part of the Metasploit Framework for example, some (Oracle based) examples are in the Privilege Escalation part of this presentation: https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-09/GATES/BHUSA09-Gates-OracleMetasploit-SLIDES.pdf